# how to identify multiple gpu?

Tags: amd-graphics

I have a setup of 5 NVIDIAs and 1 AMD card.

I ran lspci and got this:

```
  02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] 
  Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/580] (rev e7) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
  Subsystem: Sapphire Technology Limited Sapphire Radeon RX 580 Pulse 8GB
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 131
```

When I go to /sys/class/drm/  there are multiple cards listed... card0, card1, card2, card3, card4 and card5.  How do I identify which one is my amd rx 580?

I'm looking to overclock my amd rx 580.  /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_sclk_od.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ls -l /sys/class/drm/` to see the symlinks pointing to the specific devices in `/sys/devices` or in another directory

Probably it is possible to use the ID from `lspci` to identify your card.